# Find next value of AUTO_INCREMENT column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I am using MySQL.
I want to retrieve the next value that the AUTO_INCREMENT column will take without entering a new record.

```
create table ABC(id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,name char(10));
```

In oracle I would have used `sequencename.nextval();` But what to I use in MySQL?

Here is why I did **not** use

```
select max(id) from ABC;
```

Suppose I have an entry with id=2. Now column id will take the next value as 3.
Before I create a record with id=3, If I delete the record with id=2. 
The answer for query I mentioned will be 2. But I want the actual value 3, which the auto_increment column will anyway take.

Comment: neither. I want to receive a value. But these answers print a description. Not a retrievable value

Comment: http://www.microshell.com/database/mysql/emulating-nextval-function-to-get-sequence-in-mysql/

Comment: USE THIS CODE: `SELECT (IFNULL(max(id),0) + 1 ) as id from table`. 
IFNULL will be helpful if there is no record in the table

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Query table status like this:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE `Name` = 'table_name'
```

Now in result you will get a column named `Auto_increment`. This is the value You were asking for.

In JAVA:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser, connectionPassword);
stmt = conn.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE `Name` = 'table_name'");
rs.next();
String nextid = rs.getString("Auto_increment");
```

Full example here: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-jdbc-to-query-a-mysql-database.html

Comment: Yes it is giving an output. How do I retrieve that value from the status displayed?
select auto_increment from(SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE `Name` = 'table_name') does not work

Comment: But in what language?

Comment: java using JDBC.
I want to receive only the value as the result in a ResultSet.

Comment: Use it as edited above.

Comment: I received an error message,

java.sql.SQLException: Column 'Auto_increment' not found.

Comment: oh sorry wrong query, code fixed... don't forget to change `table_name` to your table name.

Comment: Yes. This is simpler than schema search. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly,you could use the number of rows as indicator:

```
SELECT TABLE_ROWS+1
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_name='tableName'
AND table_schema = DATABASE();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to guarantee what value you are going to get before inserting the row. This is mostly because you will have to lock the entire table to guarantee no other thread will do an insert with "your" next value.

You can reserve a value by starting a transaction, inserting a row, getting the value and then doing a rollback. Then you can safely use that value.

It will be much simpler to just insert the row, so maybe I'm not understanding the purpose of what you are doing.

Comment: I want to perform insert query into another table, check if it is valid, and only then insert into this table.

Comment: The best way to do that would be a transaction. If you are using MyISAM the best I can think of is to insert the row, get the autoincrement value, <do other stuff>, if it fails delete the row.